# how to call a jsp page from servlet though post

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have worked with php for over 2 years now ,i have just recently shifted to my first project in java

i have a form on which i am redirecting to servlet though post, here is the code.

```
  public class Login extends HttpServlet {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Autowired
     EnfantsHibernateDAO enfantsdao;

        public Login() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }


     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

      request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/dashboard.jsp").forward(request,response);
     }

     @Override
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

      req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/dashboard.jsp").forward(req, resp);

     }
```

now inside **doPost** method i am calling a jsp page, which loads just fine i am facing an issue, 
after loading the **dashboard.jsp** from **doPost** when i refresh the **dashboard.jsp** page it shows me the form re submission alert,

now working with php what i do is redirect to another method from the post method and then load the view from that other method so that i may not get form re submission error,
my question is how i can i achieve something similar with servlet?

Comment: So your problem is actually the alert you see when you re-submit the page? This is normal browser behavior. BTW, it seems you're not sharing the code you're using for refreshing the page.

Comment: yes the alert is the issue , that is because i am calling the jsp page from inside the doPost method what i need to do is call another method and render the jsp page from there

Comment: and my question is not even close of being duplicate as BalusC did! i amazed people dont even read the question before adding it as duplicate

Comment: i amazed people dont even read the answer before complaining it being duplicate

Comment: my base question is related to redirection! not get and post sir

Comment: your base problem is related to misunderstanding get and post (and the duplicate shows how to properly use them, including performing a redirect), try **reading** the answer instead of only looking at code